# Local variable not initialized on second call VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a very annoying issue with the code on VS2010 below:

```
template <class N>
size_t NumericIndex<N>::GetPageIndex(const PageRef& page, Id id) const
{
  size_t size=page->entries.size();

  if (size>0) {
    size_t left=0;
    size_t right=size-1;
    size_t mid;

    while (left<=right) {
      mid=(left+right)/2;
      if (page->entries[mid].startId<=id &&
          (mid+1>=size || page->entries[mid+1].startId>id)) {
        return mid;
      }
      else if (page->entries[mid].startId<id) {
        left=mid+1;
      }
      else {
        right=mid-1;
      }
    }
  }

  return size;
}
```

And it is called by the method below:

```
template <class N>
bool NumericIndex<N>::GetOffset(const N& id,
                                FileOffset& offset) const
{
  size_t r=GetPageIndex(root,id);
  ...
}
```

The issue is that, on the first call of the method everything is fine, `size`, `left` and `right` are well initialized, but on the second call, it jumps directly to the line `while (left<=right) {`, every instuctions before this line is skipped, and `right` is initialized with garbage.

Do you have any idea where the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

The code is part of the project [libosmscout](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libosmscout/).

[edit]

Arne Mertz solved the question. Actually it was the second pass of the loop. And as size_t is an unsigned type, we have a overflow when mid == 0 and right=mid-1.

The fix code should be:

```
template <class N>
size_t NumericIndex<N>::GetPageIndex(const PageRef& page, Id id) const
{
  size_t size=page->entries.size();

  if (size>0) {
    size_t left=0;
    size_t right=size-1;
    size_t mid;

    while (left<=right) {
      mid=(left+right)/2;
      if (page->entries[mid].startId<=id &&
          (mid+1>=size || page->entries[mid+1].startId>id)) {
        return mid;
      }
      else if (page->entries[mid].startId<id) {
        left=mid+1;
      }
      else {
        if (mid == 0) {
          return size;
        }
        right=mid-1;
      }
    }
  }

  return size;
}
```

Comment: wild think: do you have a static member which is `size`?

Comment: Is this a release build? And what is the value of size?

Comment: No this a debug build. I have no static member size.

Comment: On the fist call, size == 2. On the second call, the line that is supposed to initialized size is skipped, and in the debugger size is still 2.

Comment: Have you built with debugging options and without optimization? Have you looked at the `this` pointer in the second pass? (Sometimes such strange things happen if you call functions on a nullpointer)

Comment: And: Are you sure it is the second call of the function and not the second pass through the while loop? Yes, that question might sound stupid, but sometimes one just doesn't see the obvious...

Comment: @ArneMertz Haha, that's it, it was the second pass of the loop, and because size_t is an unsigned type, we always have left<=right. Thank's a lot.

Comment: well that's a hint that your algorithm might be flawed. As far as I can see its some kind of binary search?

Comment: I think so, it's not my code, so I don't have really looked deeply in the code.